# Any Elisp equivalent of Python's inspect.cleandoc?

Tags: indentation

When working with code generation, Python's `inspect.cleandoc` is quite useful, as it allows to write inline code in a multi-line string and then automatically adjust the indentation.

```
# -- Input:
def generate_code():
    return inspect.cleandoc(f"""
        if cond():
            do_stuff()
        else:
            do_other_stuff()
    """)
print(generate_code())

# -- Output:
if cond():
    do_stuff()
else:
    do_other_stuff()
```

Is there any similar convenience function in Emacs Lisp?

### Motivation

Since it came up: The motivation for the question was trying to improve the following snippet:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert "\nimport os"
          "\nimport sys"
          "\ndef _dotemacs_shellsend_setup():"
          "\n    sourcefile = " (format "%S" source-file)
          "\n    sourcedir = os.path.dirname(sourcefile)"
          "\n    print()"
          "\n    print(f'Sending file {sourcefile}...')"
          "\n    if os.getcwd() != sourcedir:"
          "\n        os.chdir(sourcedir)"
          "\n        print(f'{os.getcwd() = }')"
          "\n    if sys.argv[:1] != [sourcefile]:"
          "\n        sys.argv[:1] = [sourcefile]"
          "\n        print(f'{sys.argv[0] = }')"
          "\n_dotemacs_shellsend_setup()")
  (python-shell-send-buffer nil msg))
```

While editing this code, I several times ended up forgetting trailing newlines (hence moving them to the front), or accidentally deleting trailing double-quotes.

What I want to do instead is something like

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert (UNKNOWN-FUNCTION (concat "
      import os"
      import sys"
      def _dotemacs_shellsend_setup():
          sourcefile = " (format "%S" source-file) "
          sourcedir = os.path.dirname(sourcefile)
          print()
          print(f'Sending file {sourcefile}...')
          if os.getcwd() != sourcedir:
              os.chdir(sourcedir)
              print(f'{os.getcwd() = }')
          if sys.argv[:1] != [sourcefile]:
              sys.argv[:1] = [sourcefile]
              print(f'{sys.argv[0] = }')
      _dotemacs_shellsend_setup()")
  (python-shell-send-buffer nil msg))))
```

The aim is to strip the common indentation of all lines, in order to generate correctly *not*-indented Python code, while keeping the indentation of the in-code template consistent with the surrounding code structure.

While such a function wouldn't be *too* hard to write, I am interested in whether there is builtin functionality for this.

Comment: I don't see how that would be useful, since Elisp is a LISP.  In other words, macros exist.

Comment: @aadcg I added an example. The current use-case was generated python code in a customized `python-shell-send-buffer` wrapper. So basically the use-case is generating non-lisp code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just leverage python for this.

```
(shell-command-to-string
 (format "python -c \"import inspect; print(inspect.cleandoc('''%s'''))\""
     (let ((source-file "test.py"))
       (concat "
                   import os
                   import sys
                   def _dotemacs_shellsend_setup():
                       sourcefile = " (format "%S" source-file) "
                       sourcedir = os.path.dirname(sourcefile)
                       print()
                       print(f'Sending file {sourcefile}...')
                       if os.getcwd() != sourcedir:
                           os.chdir(sourcedir)
                           print(f'{os.getcwd() = }')
                       if sys.argv[:1] != [sourcefile]:
                           sys.argv[:1] = [sourcefile]
                           print(f'{sys.argv[0] = }')
                   _dotemacs_shellsend_setup()"))))
```

This outputs a string:

```
import os
import sys
def _dotemacs_shellsend_setup():
    sourcefile = test.py
    sourcedir = os.path.dirname(sourcefile)
    print()
    print(f'Sending file {sourcefile}...')
    if os.getcwd() != sourcedir:
        os.chdir(sourcedir)
        print(f'{os.getcwd() = }')
    if sys.argv[:1] != [sourcefile]:
        sys.argv[:1] = [sourcefile]
        print(f'{sys.argv[0] = }')
_dotemacs_shellsend_setup()
```

Comment: What I am trying to solve is the mismatch between the indentation of the code-generation template and the surrounding Emacs lisp, without having to resorting to writing one string literal per line. In your solution, this mismatch present heavily.

Comment: Tried to clarify it more.

Comment: I updated my answer to get closer to what you want.

Comment: My first thought was "its awkward to use an external process for string processing". Implementing a `cleandoc` emacs lisp function myself though, it turns out to be quite acceptable though, given the overhead. (Though the naming confusion, where `python` may refer either to a python3 or a python2 executable is an issue.)

Comment: You could always be specific about which python executable to use, even with a full path to it.